# Как добавить несколько ссылок в httpProtocol в web.config файле?

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net, csp

Не могу добавить несколько ссылок, отрабатывает та, которая стоит спереди , если поменять их местами, опять же отработает, но первая. Пробовал разделять их запятыми, но результат тот же.

В примере которые я привожу ниже отработает только http://link1.net

```xml
<httpProtocol>
    <customHeaders>
        <remove name="X-Powered-By"/>
        <add name="Content-Security-Policy"
             value="script-src 'unsafe-eval';script-src-elem 'unsafe-inline' http://link1.net, http://link2.net;"/>
    </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

Прочитал https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/security/csp но ответа на мой вопрос не нашел.

Comment: @aepot Спасибо за совет, прочитал https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/security/csp но ответа на мой вопрос не нашел.

Comment: Ну я не спец по web.config, подождем, быть может кто-то из спецов ответит. Вообще, то что у вас написано в строке не соответствует спецификации синтаксически. Адреса через пробел пишутся.